# Run batch file each time a specific file is saved

Tags: batch-file, triggers, save, task, scheduler

I have a shared Excel file on a network, and I want to create a backup each time the file is saved in case it gets overwritten or deleted by mistake.

I created a batch file to save a backup of the file with timestamp in the filename (found it here:https://datatofish.com/backup-file-timestamp/).

Now I'm looking for a way to trigger the batch file each time the file is saved so I will have a history of all the changes and backups in case of a problem. Is there a simple way to do that? Maybe using Task Scheduler? I've never used Task Scheduler so I would need a detailed description.

Thanks.

Comment: I did that before posting here, but did not find anything helpful. Can you point me to a resource that describes Task Scheduler event triggers?

Comment: Would you consider using a folder monitor application.  Your folder monitor could monitor the file and perform whatever command you want.    In addition, have you considered just using the file versioning within Excel?